# Any way to make snippets available inside quote marks in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

One thing I find incredibly annoying about VSCode is that none of the defined snippets will be available inside a set of quote marks. This means that if you have a snippet to trigger, say a set of double curly brackets, you can't use a snippet to trigger them inside, say, an anchor tag (e.g. Laravel: home).

This annoyed me so much that I ended up using BetterTouchTool to configure Cmd+[ to render 2 sets of curly brackets and move the cursor to the middle.

But there should be a way to do this in VSCode.Atom has this functionality out of the box, but it's so annoying and doesn't have many of the other features of VSCode without adding a lot of packages.

Is there any way to trigger this functionality inside VSCode? Any extensions that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Withing strings it is possible. If by quote marks I am assuming within strings. If so

You need to modify your editor snippet settings.

Go to your settings, search for quick, find this option

[image: editor settings]

And add this to `settings.json`

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true, // you need this if you want ctrl+space to work elsewhere. 
        "strings": true // this is your relevant option
    }
```

You can use Intellisense to find more options regarding this too! (ctrl+space) within that object.

Comment: yes strings I add this at the end of the file or where the file was opened

Comment: Didn't it already add the  value? you just need to replace that with the code in the ans.

Comment: Yes works! Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately not all snippets work as expected. In PHP file if I switch to <?php ?> and write single quote in between php tags, no HTML snippets are available to choose from the list